# Get constructor by value option in Elm (0.19.1)

Tags: elm, algebraic-data-types

I have some types:

```
type alias Type1 = { name : String }
type alias Type2 = { name : String, age : Int }
type S
  = S1 Type1
  | S2 Type2
```

So, when I want to build my info I can do the following:

```
a = S1 { name = "Name1" }
b = S2 { name = "Name2", age = 100 }
```

Now, I would like to get its constructor (`S1` or `S2`) based on the info passed as parameter to the `constructorByData` function. Examples:

```
constructorByData a -- It should be returned `S1`
constructorByData b -- It should be returned `S2`
```

This is my aproach:

```
constructorByData : S -> (a -> S)
constructorByData s =
  case s of
    S1 _ -> S1
    S2 _ -> S2
```

*Please, note that the above code does not work. I get the following error:*

```
-- TYPE MISMATCH ---------------------------------------------------------- REPL

Something is off with the 2nd branch of this `case` expression:

14|       S2 _ -> S2
                  ^^
This `S2` value is a:

    Type2 -> S

But the type annotation on `constructorByData` says it should be:

    a -> S

-- TYPE MISMATCH ---------------------------------------------------------- REPL

Something is off with the 1st branch of this `case` expression:

13|       S1 _ -> S1
                  ^^
This `S1` value is a:

    Type1 -> S

But the type annotation on `constructorByData` says it should be:

    a -> S
```

The main reason I want to do this is because I want to do the following by generalizing the message:

```
type Field
  = Name
  | Age

type Msg
  = UpdateFieldString S Field String
  | UpdateFieldInt S Field Int

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
  case msg of
    UpdateFieldString s field value -> updateFieldString model s field value
    UpdateFieldInt s field value -> updateFieldInt model s field value
```

And is for this I need the constructor in `updateField{String, Int}` functions

Comment: What's the problem? Why does it not work?

Comment: @glennsl I have added the error

Comment: `S1` and `S2` have different types, so you can't have a function returning both on different branches. You can make a sum type out of them, but this begins to beg the question: why are you doing this? What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: There's actually two problems. One is that the types of the returned values are incompatible, as @RobinZigmond pointed out. The other is that the type annotation is incompatible with both the returned functions. A type parameter does not mean "whatever", it means "anything". It says the returned function should accept any type of value, but they both accept only one specific type, which also happen to be incompatible. In technical terms, the type annotation is more general than the actual type of the functions returned.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, I have added the real problem!

Comment: As mentioned previously, you shouldn't generalize messages. They're not reusable functions, they're descriptions of what's happening in your system. Your real problem is at an even higher layer of abstraction.

Comment: @glennsl but I want to generalize because I actually have a very complicated model. You can think of a huge table, surely you would not like to have to create a message to update cell 1, cell 2, cell 3, ... In my case it is not a table, it is somewhat more irregular structure.

Comment: Then your model is probably wrong. Getting the model right is crucial for getting everything else right, so you should focus on that first. But to help you with that we'd need to know the problem you are trying to model, and what your current model actually is.